# How to list log files in fluent-bit?

Tags: docker, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am using fluent-bit version 1.6.2 in docker with the following INPUT section:

```
[INPUT]
    Name    tail
    Path    /fluent-bit/log/containers/*/*-json.log
    Tag     docker.log
    Parser  docker
```

How can I list those log files? I can't get a shell using `docker exec -it`. I want to tag those files separately. I'd like a separate tag for each container name.

edit: I guess what I am asking is can those asterisks be replaced by the container name or is that assumption not correct?

Comment: Are you referring to files residing at `Path`? By logging those files separately, do you mean to log the contents of each file separately with unique tags, right? If so, you might need to list the absolute paths in separate INPUT sections. The other possibility could be to use the [Exec](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/exec) plugin but I'm not sure if that would be feasible here. With the first approach using `tail`, a bash script could be written to add those INPUT sections against each file to automate it.

Comment: Yes, I want a separate INPUT for each path but don't want to just guess what those paths may be, exec and command are not available in the fluentbit container.

Comment: Then, `tail` with an INPUT section for each separate file would work for your scenario.

Comment: Sure, if I knew what those paths were.

Comment: Isn't this the known format `/fluent-bit/log/containers/*/*-json.log`? Or, the paths dynamically change?

Comment: Yes, but I need to replace the asterisk with the actual path and file name. Other than guessing, how do I find them out? Should I just use `docker ps` and replace the first asterisk with the container name?

Comment: I'm not sure about `docker ps`. Can you do an `ls` or `tree` at `/fluent-bit/log/containers/` to check the files?

Comment: From what I understand and can see, the container does not have command (ls) or exec support after version 1.0.

Comment: Can you please share a reference to that? Which OS image is this container based on? Doesn't it provide a bash or shell in interactive mode?

Comment: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-docker-image/issues/19

Comment: Ah, I see! However, you can use the debug image for this which supports these commands, just to set it all up correctly. Later, you can switch to the non-debug one. See: https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit-docker-image/issues/19#issuecomment-461096716.

Comment: It's already running in production, I just want to change the tagging.

Comment: How do you want to tag those? Example?

Comment: By container name, a tag for each.

Comment: Please take a look at [Rewrite Tag](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/rewrite-tag) filter. Maybe, you need to have the container name inside the JSON log if it's not already there that you would later be able to create the new tag. That's just an idea. You might want to explore in this direction to see if it works for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit to the question.

Comment: I guess you can in case the container name is static. But, you need to test it. And, in case of multiple containers, you might want to update each config file with the correct container name before firing those up.

Comment: The container name is set in the `docker-compose.yml` file so they would be static. If  the path asterisks do correlate to the container name please write that up as an answer.

Comment: I guess you need to test that first. And, please post the answer too as you have a better understanding of the exact use-case and its constraints.